# Google Analytics Tracking ID after new keystore?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm using the tracker (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032385?hl=en) provided with google analytics to see where my users are clicking on the app.

After the first release, I had to change the keystore of my app for some reasons. This of course affected google maps, but it seems that it changed the behavior of the tracking feature as well.

From the first version to the second one, I added a lot of new features. However NONE of them are displayed on the google analytics tab reporting the user click events.

Do I have to update the tracking ID? Is it any change to make on the admin panel in order to make it work again after having change the keystore of my app?

Thanks in advance.